# Standard input in sort utility

Tags: command-line

I read in a textbook that sort command accepts input either  from  a  file named  on the command  line or  from  standard  input. I know about cat command accepting stdin:

```
$ cat
stdin
stdin
```

What can be an example of it with sort command?

Answer (score 5):

In exactly the same way

```
$ sort
abc
xyz
def
Ctrl+D
abc
def
xyz
```

More often though, it would be used with a *pipe*

```
somecommand-that-produces-unsorted-output | sort
```

Answer (score 4):

```
printf "omega\r\nbeta\r\nalpha\r\n" | sort  

alpha  
beta  
omega
```

A use case would be if you wanted to sort output from any given command after a lot of cut, split, whatever.